# React-Navigation update a header icon from itself

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to update a header icon using itself. I have a `heart` icon in the `headerRight` component:

```js
const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

navigation.setOptions({
   headerRight: () => (<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setEnabled(prev => !prev)}>{enabled ? <HeartFill/> : <HeartOutline/>}</TouchableOpacity>)
});
```

But this doesn't work since `navigation.setOptions()` is never 're-called' to update to the correct icon. How can I make a child update itself in `react-navigation`?

Instead of `setEnabled` I could pass `navigation.setOptions()` again but that would just make me do some endless nesting if I want to toggle between more than 2 states.

Comment: Have you tried `useEffect` with `enabled` as dependency?

Comment: Yes that works, but isn't it an anti-pattern to use `useEffect` pure to rerender a component? Based on https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect the 'handling' of components should take place in their own `onPress` functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep it pure, could you try this?

```js
const Parent = () => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => <Child /> 
  })

  return null
}
```

```js
const Child = () => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => setEnabled(prev => !prev)}>{enabled ? <HeartFill/> : <HeartOutline/>}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Comment: This works. Guess I'd have to make a wrapper for `headerRight` that handles everything related to the actions of the icons because I want to allow both the `parent` and `child` to make changes to the header. In the parent I could still use `setOptions` and in the child I would build a custom header with everything I need. Seems a bit weird to have to do this but I guess it's ment this way?